# Making a custom text editor the default one

Tags: windows-7, notepad

In Windows, there's a "edit" menu option when you right-click on a unknown file-type. When you select it, the sucky Notepad thing will open that file.

How can I change Notepad with another editor, like Notepad2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [Notepad Replacer](http://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/) to exchange notepad with an editor of your choice, this is the easiest way i know.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on file, then go to `property`, then go to `open with`

Then click on Browse, then go to program file -> your new text editor

Then select this file as default application to view the content

Now you have done and whenever you open any text document it get opened in  whatever text editor you have selected.